# Python program not displaying gateway and network ip

Tags: python, ip, output, local, gateway

```
import socket
import struct

def get_default_gateway_linux():
    with open("/proc/net/route") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            fields = line.strip().split()
            if fields[1] != '00000000' or not int(fields[3], 16) & 2:
                continue

            return socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", int(fields[2], 16)))


def getNetworkIp():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(('bt', 0))
    return s.getsockname()[0] 


    print "Your Machine IP has been detected as "+getNetworkIp()

    print "Your Gateway IP has been detected as "+get_default_gateway_linux()
```

the above code neither shows any error nor any output when executed in backtrack 5 R3
please help me regarding this code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 print statements are tabbed/spaced.  Remove them and it will work as I have confirmed this to work on CentOS 6.5:

```
def getNetworkIp():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(('localhost',0))
    return s.getsockname()[0]

print "Your Machine IP has been detected as "+getNetworkIp()

print "Your Gateway IP has been detected as "+get_default_gateway_linux()
```

Comment: Oh my god! this is a bullshit in python! you are a life saver dude thank you mastashake

Comment: Aww, it's not Python's fault.  It's a simple mistake than can happen to the best of us.  Glad it worked out.  :)

Comment: In python, whitespace matters. I wonder if @ZainUlAbidin ever got used to that.

Comment: lolz . i am not very handy at python you are right @GeoffCrompton

Answer (score 0):

This may be too simple to be true, but the last two lines are part of getNetworkIp(), since they are indented as such.

I even get an indentation error from Python when I try this.

Note that when I move those last 2 print statements out to column 0, I get another error, because I get a 'name or service not known' error ... but that's probably an old Linux/Python problem, or need root.

Anyway, try un-indenting those last two print statements.